# Java Servlet Pass Value from Filter to Servlet Code

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a Java HTTP Servlet running in Tomcat. I have a filter that is doing some pre-processing on requests. The filter contains some if/else logic.
I want to set a boolean value in my servlet processing code (doGet/doPost) based on which action my filter performed.

**What is the correct way to pass this information from my filter to my servlet method?** One idea is to update the request via a setAttribute method, but I am not sure if this is the right way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)` method you can use the `request` object and set an attribute using `request.setAttribute` method and then get it in your servlet using `request.getAttribute`.

See docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)